# Js Fiddle into dDreamweaver

Tags: jsfiddle

my animation works in JS Fiddle, but when I put the code into Dreamweaver the picture will show up in the webpage but the animation will no longer work.

Maybe if anyone has a sample template for the Dreamweaver HTML i can place my .js file links into?

Comment: Are you expecting Dreamweaver to show you some animation in the editor?

Comment: There is not enough information in your question. What is your animation's code? Are you looking directly at the editor or at a page that it generated?